# Help to draw attached diagram in tikz

Tags: tikz-trees

Kindly help to draw this diagram in tikz. How many level should I include for this type of diagram. The issue is not using forks down in the next level.Thank you

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
% Preamble

% Package used for input and output display.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Package used for diagram.
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

% Page layout.
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

% Begin document.
\begin{document}
% Preamble.


\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
      thesis/.style={draw,rectangle,fill=white,text width=5 em, minimum height=5mm},
      parent/.style={draw,rectangle,fill=white,rounded corners=5, text width=5.5em, text centered, minimum height=10mm, node distance=7em, minimum width=8em},
every node/.style={draw,rectangle,fill=white,text width=2.7em, text centered, minimum height=6mm,node distance=1em},
level1/.style ={level distance=1.8cm},]

 
\node[parent]{\textbf{Data}} [edge from parent fork down] [sibling distance=3cm]
     child[level1] {node[thesis] {Data1}}
     child[level1]  {node[thesis] {Data2}}
     child[level1]  {node[thesis] {Data3}}
     child[level1]  {node[thesis] {Data4}}
     child[level1]  {node[thesis] {Data5}}
     child[level1]  {node[thesis] {Data6}}
;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello. You won't get any help doing this huge tree without sharing a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of what you already tried, and asking for specific solution to a specific issue you're struggling with.

Comment: Do you mean levels of a tree? You can count how many levels there are: I would say it is about 9 ... But this and also whether this actually has any meaning depends on how you are going to type this tree.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much. I m working on it and will post the code. The main issues is how to remove fork down to produce linear diagram.

Comment: Jasper Habicht,Yes  levels of the tree. I still working on it. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hello all, can anyone help me how to complete the above figure. I am stuck wether to continue with trees library or forest package?